# Tie cell content to comment box in another cell

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to show content of a cell (currently text string) as a comment in another cell.  Also, is it possible that such connection would update itself should the test content change ?
Cell containing text string is at the end of a large spreadsheet. If content of such cell could be shown as a comment in the visible section of the screen, I would not have to constantly scroll back and forth to access the far away cell.

Appreciate suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your VBA in the `Worksheet` (**not a module**) that the value comes from.

The `sheet1` is the sheet you want the comment to go to

The `Intersect range` is the value you want to use as the comment and the `with range` is the cell you want the comment on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cmt As String

'Check Target Range has value
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

    'Check value isn't blank
    If Target.Value <> "" Then

    'Take target contents and store to string
    cmt = Target.Value

        'Change sheets and set comment of desired range
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("A1").ClearComments
            .Range("A1").AddComment Text:=cmt
        End With

    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to link a cell to a comment without using VBA.

However, you can link a cell to a text box by selecting the box and then entering the cell address in the formula bar.

Additonally, it's possible to copy the range that you are interested in keeping track of and pasting it as a linked picture elsewhere in your worksheet. As values are changed in the worksheet, the picture will update

Answer (score 0):

This is not, strictly speaking, an answer to your question, but it might be a solution to your problem.  As I understand it, your problem is

> I want to be able to refer to (i.e., look at) the value(s) of “far away” cell(s) (“at the end of the worksheet”) while I am working in the upper left (home) corner of the worksheet, and I want to be able to do this without scrolling back and forth to the “far away” cell(s).

So link the “far away” cell(s) to cells in the home area of Sheet2. 
You can look at them with one click of the mouse (or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>)) and then get back to Sheet1 just as quickly, without losing your place.